# Is it possible to write an "if" statement along with an "else" for a list comprehension in Python?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

If possible, why the code below is invalid? (to get [2,2,4,5]):

```
tsil=[1,2,3,4]
added=[i+1 if i!=2 else i=2 for i in tsil]
```

Is there an inbuilt way of leaving a certain element (ex: all the "2"s) unchanged without skipping them?

Comment: use a conditional expression

Comment: `added=[i+1 if i!=2 else 2 for i in tsil]`

Comment: Because you are using an assignment where an expression is expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tsil=[1,2,3,4]
added=[i+1 if i!=2 else 2 for i in tsil]
```